# ¿Cómo puedo esperar a la ejecución de un callback en javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, post, callback

Estoy implementando un back end y tengo un problema. El front end manda una petición post al backend con sus datos de usuario. El back end, toma esa petición, añade unos campos y la manda a un servidor de autenticación (keycloak) para que le dé un token de acceso. El problema es que el back end no espera a que llegue la respuesta del servidor de autenticación y manda en la respuesta un token undefined y poco después llega el token del servidor de autenticación. ¿Como puedo hacer para esperar a que llegue el token al callback y así poder mandarlo al usuario?

Este es el código que envía la petición al servidor de autenticación y debería esperar para continuar.

```js
request.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/token',form:send_form}, 
       function(err,httpResponse,body) {
      //  console.log(parse(body));
      let body_json = parse(body); 
      console.log(body_json.access_token);
      // este es el callback al que se deberia esperar. 
    });
```

Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Deberías agregar el código desde donde se llama a este método,  de lo contrario se dificulta dar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso puedes ayudarte de la función de php ***isset()***

isset() determina si una variable está **definida** y no es **NULL**, es decir, si un variable existe o si esta vacia, ademas esta función puede recibir más de una variable para evaluar, pero sólo devolverá **true** si **todas** las variables existen o no estan vacias.

Se puede comprobar en *PHP* si ya se recibió el *token*, de la siguiente manera:

```
if(isset($_POST['tu_token'])){
   // Respuesta hacia el front
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, estaría bien una explicación sobre qué es `isset` o dar detalles más relevantes, [editando la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/284017/edit).